# Xamarin Listview don't show the observable Collection

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using `Xamarin.Forms` MVVM to develop my app, and don't found what I'm doing wrong, I have an `ObservableCollection` with the values from web API, and when I set a break point all the values are good even in the view when I see the values of the binding source everything have the value, but the values are not showing up in my `ListView`.

**Here is the ViewModel**

```
class DatosMedicosViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ApiService apiService;

    private ObservableCollection<Land> land;
    private bool isRefreshing;

    public ObservableCollection<Land> Lands
    {
        get { return this.land; }
        set { SetValue(ref this.land, value); }
    }

    public bool IsRefreshing
    {
        get { return this.isRefreshing; }
        set { SetValue(ref this.isRefreshing, value); }
    }

    public DatosMedicosViewModel()
    {
        this.apiService = new ApiService();
        this.LoadLand();
    }

    private async void LoadLand()
    {
        this.IsRefreshing = true;
        var connection = await this.apiService.CheckConnection();
        if (!connection.IsSuccess)
        {
            this.IsRefreshing = false;
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
                "Error",
                connection.Message,
                "Accept");
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
            return;
        }

        var response = await this.apiService.GetList<Land>(
           "url Base",
           "prefix",
           "Controller");

        if (!response.IsSuccess)
        {
            this.IsRefreshing = false;
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
                "Error",
                response.Message,
                "Accept"
                );
            return;
        }

        var list = (List<Land>)response.Result;
        this.Lands = new ObservableCollection<Land>(list);
        this.IsRefreshing = false;
    }

    public ICommand RefreshCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(LoadLand);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the View**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ARLAPP.Views.ConsultaPage"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             BindingContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
             Title="Lands">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout 
            BindingContext="{Binding Lands}"
            Padding="5">
            <StackLayout>
                <Image 
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                WidthRequest="300"
                Source="UserIcon"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                <Label Text="Mark"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       FontSize="Medium"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <ListView
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Lands}"
                HasUnevenRows="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Label   
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    Text="{Binding Currency}"/>

                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Here how I call the view**

```
if (this.PageName == "Lands")
{
    MainViewModel.GetInstance().Lands= new LandViewModel();
    Application.Current.MainPage = new LandMasterPage();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the Land entity class?

Comment: yeap, the class and all have the values that i want, the only thing that is wrong is the listview that does not show those values.

 public class Land
    {
        public int Name{ get; set; }
        public int Currency{ get; set; }
        public string Lenght{ get; set; }
        public decimal Language{ get; set; }
    }

Comment: You need to inherit INotifyPropertyChanged interface and change your properties to notify whenever the value is assigned to it.. some what similar to    private string cardImage;
        public string CardImage
        {
            get
            {
                return cardImage;
            }
            set
            {
                cardImage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `BindingContext`. I think you are setting it wrong in your view.

In your top-level `StackLayout` you set the the `BindingContext` to your property: `BindingContext="{Binding Lands}"`. And in your `ListView` you set the `ItemsSource` also to this property: `ItemsSource="{Binding Lands}"`. That won't work because the `ListView` is trying to bind to a property `Lands` inside your `BindingContext`, which is also set to `Lands`.

Remove the `BindingContext` from your top-level `StackLayout`, because you don't need it.

Ensure the `BindingContext` of your page `ConsultaPage` is set to your view-model `DatosMedicosViewModel`.

Sample of setting the bindingcontext (abstract code):

```
var mypage = new ConsultaPage();
mypage.BindingContext = new DatosMedicosViewModel();

await Navigation.PushAsync(mypage);

// Load your data in OnAppearing() of the page-event
```

This should solve your binding-problem.

Side-Note: As Abdul Gani said in the comments: Ensure you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, but I assume you do this already in your `BaseViewModel` and call the NotifyChanged-Event in your `SetValue`-Method.